# showing that the fields with $p^2$ elements are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I have to show that all field with $p^2$ ($p$ prime) elements are isomorphic to each other. Let $F$ be any such field. Since $F$ has characteristics $p$, it contains a prime field $\Bbb F_p$, so it can be said that $F$ is quadratic extension of $\Bbb F_p$. Let $x =a + b \alpha$ where $a, b \in \Bbb F_p$ and $\alpha \in F$. Then, by [Frobenius endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)
$$x^{p^2} - x = 0$$
so elements of $F$ are elements of $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ as well. Every field with $p^2$ elements is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_{p^2}$. Thus there exists one up to isomorphism.

Is my reasoning correct? If not, I would be grateful some hints. There is another method in [this book (page 210)](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FTe6.pdf) and problem is from page no 57. I just don't understand it and I don't see why my idea is wrong or right.

Comment: What do you mean "and so elements of $F$ are elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ as well" ? What I recommend you do, is consider $K$ an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$, then as $F$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (since the extension has finite degree), then there is an embedding $F\to K$. Now you can look at the image of $F$ under this embedding (and there you can apply what you did)

Comment: @Max $\Bbb F_{p^2}$ the set of roots of $x^{p^2}-x$, my reasoning is if some element $y=a + \alpha b \in F$ satisfies this property then there must be some isomorphism that maps $y \to x$. Thanks for your valuable recommendation too. I am looking onto it.

Comment: But the point is precisely to show that $\Bbb{F}_{p^2}$ is thus well-defined. That's what considering the algebraic closure as I suggested allows you to do, because then you can talk about "the set of roots of $X^{p^2}-X$ [in the algebraic closure]", and then you can define your mapping "$y\to x$"

Comment: Ah thanks Max :) I understand your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field such that $|\mathbb{F}|=p^2$.

It is not difficult to show that $a^{\,p^2}=a \,\,\,\forall a\in \mathbb{F}$.

Let $\mathbb{F}_p\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ the prime field of $\mathbb{F}$, and $f(x)=x^{p^2}-x \in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Since $f(x)$ has at most $p^2$ roots and $f(a)=0\,\, \forall a \in \mathbb{F}$, then $\mathbb{F}$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Now you can use the fact that any two splitting fields of a polynomial $f(x)$ over the same field are isomorphic.